# A consistency question

Tags: logic, model-theory

Let $X=P_f(\mathbb{N})$ be the set of all finite subsets of the set of natural numbers. Let $S^*$ be a binary relation over $X$, defined by: for each $A,B\in X$, $\langle A,B \rangle \in S^*$ if and only if $A\cap B=\emptyset$.

Let $L$ be a vocabulary which contains binary relations $S$ and $R$, and contains a constant symbol $c_A$ for each $A\in X$.

Now, let $M$ be a structure to interpret $L$, defined by:

- the domain is $X$, $S^M=S^*$,
- $R^M$ is defined so that for each $A,B\in X$, $\langle A,B \rangle \in R^M$ if and only if $A\subseteq B$, and
- $c_A^{M}=A$ for each $A\in X$.

In addition, for each $n\in \mathbb{N}$, let $A_n=\{0,1,2,...,n-1\}$ (and  $A_0=\emptyset$).

Let $T$ be the complete theory of $M$. We define $T_1$, $T_2$, and $T_3$ in $L^+=L \cup \{d\}$, where $d$ is a new constant symbol:
\begin{align*}
T_1 &= T \cup \lbrace S(c_{A_n},d)\land R(c_{\lbrace n,n+1,...,2n\rbrace},d)\mid n\in \mathbb{N}\rbrace\\
T_2&=T \cup \lbrace (S(c_{\lbrace n+1 \rbrace},d)\rightarrow R(c_{\lbrace n\rbrace},d)\mid n\in \mathbb{N}\rbrace\\
T_3&=T \cup \lbrace (S(c_{\lbrace 2n \rbrace},d)\land R(c_{\lbrace 2n+1\rbrace},d)\mid n\in \mathbb{N}\rbrace
\end{align*}

- Prove that $T_1$ is inconsistent.
- Prove that $T_2$ is consistent, and it has a model which is an expansion of $M$ to $L^+$.
- Prove that $T_3$ is consistent, but it does not have a model which is an expansion of $M$ to $L^+$.

Comment: "Let $X$ be a set of every final set of the natural numbers set" makes no sense. Did you mean "Let $X$ be the set of all *finite* subsets of the set of natural numbers"?

Comment: Assuming this is the case, I edited your post. I also made many edits to improve grammar and formatting. I recommend looking at the changes I made, so you can improve your future questions.

Comment: @AlexKruckman thank you! And indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The formulas $R(c_A,x)\to\lnot S(c_A,x)$ are valid in $M$ for every nonempty $A$, and so are $R(c_B,x)\to R(c_A,x)$ and $S(c_B,x)\to S(c_A,x)$ whenever $A\subseteq B$.
   So, $T_1$ implies that both $S(c_{\{1\}},d)$ and $R(c_{\{1\}},d)$ holds (taking the formula for $n=1,2$), which is a contradiction.
2. and 3. You can verify that for every finite subset of the given formulas, one can find interpretation of $d$ that satisfies those. So, you can use compactness to conclude. However, a $d\in X$ in neither cases exists which satisfies all the formulas at once, as it would have infinite many elements.

Comment: First of all, thank you!!! Second, can you explain to me why an incorrect choice of n implies a contradiction? because as I know, I need to find that there exist $d$ of a certain M, such that the formula of $T_1$ holds. Hence, if I show that the formula doesn't hold for $n=1,2$ how does it Imply that there isn't a model M that satisfies $T_1$?

Comment: We have $T_1\vdash S(c_{\{0,1\}},d)$ and $T_1\vdash R(c_{\{1\}},d)$. By what I wrote it implies $T_1\vdash S(c_{\{1\}},d)$ and further $T_1\vdash \lnot R(c_{\{1\}},d)$ which leads to $T_1\vdash\bot$.

Comment: thank you! I don't know if I understood the third question well. can you expand your solution to 3? thank you a lot!

Comment: Actually the second question seems wrong, as one cannot interpret symbol $d$ within $X$ for the whole $T_2$ (only for its finite subsets). In this regard there is no difference to the third question.

Comment: but how do I explain why in the third question, $T_3$ doesn't have a model which is an expansion of $M$ to $L^+$? because that is what I find hard to do.

Comment: To give an expansion of $M$ to $L^+$ means exactly to give an interpretation of the new symbol $d$ within $M$ such that it's a model of $T_3$. This is the thing which is not working neither for $T_2$, though the exercise says otherwise.

Comment: I am going to check it out, thank you for everything!!! If I will have another question, I hope you can answer it.